# MSSQL: find records that has each value of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let's say I have some the following table schema:
`year|val1|val2`
I want to get all the `val1` and `val2` columns that has all values of `year` column. I suspect I need grouping here, but I can't imagine how. 
Let's say we have set of years from query: `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR FROM table`. Let's say it returned 2000,2001. So If I have to rows as `2000|1|2` and `2001|1|2` then the query should return single row `1|2`

Comment: What types are these fields, can you show sample data and a desired result?

Comment: Definition: all val1 is GUID and val2 is nvarchar. Year is integer of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work

```
select
    value1
from 
    table as t1 inner join
    (select distinct year from table) as t2
    on t1.year=t2.year
group by
    val1 
having count(distinct t1.year)=(count(distinct t2.year) )
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to DB to try it. As soon as I will try this out I will write the result and accept question. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question. But I think you need all the values of val1 and val2 which are there for all the valid values of years.If that's the case then you have to do inner join with the table
something like this

select @yearcnt = count(distinct year) from table

or select val1,count(distint year) as totalyear from table 
group by val1
having count(distinct year) = @yearcnt